# C++: Write to/read from invalid/out of bound array index?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

First of all, I am a beginner when it comes to C++ programming. Yesterday I encountered something rather strange. I was trying to determine the length of an array via a pointer pointing towards it. Since *sizeof* didn't work I did a little Google search and ended up on this website where I found the answer that it was not possible. Instead I should put an out of bound value at the last index of the array and increment a counter until this index is reached. Because I didn't want to overwrite the information that was contained at the last index, I tried putting the out of bound value one index after the last one. I expected it to fail, but for some reason it didn't.

I thought that I made a mistake somewhere else and that the array was longer then I assigned it to be, so I made the following test:

```
int a[4];
a[20] = 42;
std::cout << a[20];
```

The output is 42 without any errors. Why does this work? This should not be valid at all, right? What's even more interesting is the fact that this works with any primitive type array. However, once I use a std::string the program instantly exists with 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for investigating the problem. See [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for the C++ aspect, and learn some about stack variables and assembly for the implementation side.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` it has a `size()` member (Or std::array in C++11).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your system just happens to not be using the memory that just happens to be `20 * sizeof(int)` bytes further from the address of your array. (From the beginning of it.) Or the memory belongs to your process and therefore you can mess with it and either break something for yourself or just by lucky coincidence break nothing.

Bottom line, don't do that :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can this only override data used by the same process or literally anything that is stored in the memory?

Comment: @CyberpunC It depends on the OS, but the general rule is: If it's data of your OS-called process or any of the sub-processes, you can do whatever you want to it. If it's memory location that just doesn't happen to be in use as of this instant, OSes usually let you write rubbish into it BUT they are free to assign this memory to a different process later, after which they will block your access to it. And of course, if there's data that OS itself is using, it's not gonna let you even breathe on it. (Literally, they usually snatch very low memory addresses.)

Comment: There is also the odd chance that the compiler optimizes this into `std::cout << 42;`, which is what the code actually does.

Comment: @BoPersson Haha, I'm off to check diasassembly, be right back! :)

Comment: @BoPersson Vs11 doesn't do that, Vs2010 doesn't do that, can't check on anything else as of current, but i guess it is a possibility.

Comment: @CyberpunC Here's a thing that could also happen even though i reckon it's very unlikely, but: Compilers can choose to optimize whatever the hell they wish unless it changes the semantics of your code. The compiler could see that you're assigning the immediate value 42 into an array, it did place it in the array but then as you called operator<< on stream std::cout, compiler would simply do std::cout<<42 as Bo persson mentioned. I reckon it's unlikely but it could possibly happen with the correct phase of the moon and stellar configuration. Did you also sacrifice a goat ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to understand is the following:
when you creating `a[4]` the compiler allocate memory for 4 integers and remember in `a` the address of the first one: (`*a == &(a[0])`).
when you read\write the compiler doesn't check if you in the bounds (because he doesn't longer have this information). and just go to the address of the requested cell of the array in the following way: `a[X] == &(a + sizeof(int) * X)`
in C++ it's the programmer responsibility to check the bounds when accessing an array.