# cl c++ runtime error while reading inaccessible memory

Tags: c++, runtime-error, cl

I have some c++ code but I don't know what. For the purposes of example let's say it is:

```
//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int T[100];

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        T[i] = i;
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<T[x]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it by `cl /O2 /nologo /EHsc main.cpp` and running by `main < inFile.in`. Let's say that inFile.in content is one number `500` and new line. The output is some random number because program reads memory under the address `T+500` and printing it. 
I want to get runtime error in such cases (any possibility of checking is something like this happened). Is this possible without access to main.cpp?
To be specific I'm running all this programmatically by Process class in C# in ASP.Net MVC Application. I want to check did program threw exception / read not reserved memory etc.

Comment: You can use a `std::vector` or `std::array`, that provide out of bounds check and will throw exceptions if it happens at runtime.

Comment: You need to make sure x is between 0 and 99 otherwise your program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: please don't lover score as this is perfectly valid question with most important part at the end of post

Answer (score 0):

Is this a feature you want to use for development purposes only, or also in your production environment?

In case of development purposes only you may try to run your application under some tool for runtime checking (like Valgrind/Dr Memory), or change the way you compile it to include runtime debug checks (is not guaranteed to work in described case, but helps in many others). Keep in mind that this will make your application *much* slower (thus should be used only for applications under development)

When it comes to production environment, I am not aware of any way of doing what you want to - in general you can only count on OS segmentation fault in case of reading out of available memory (if you have luck - if you don't it'll "work").

For the exception thing, I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean - is this "why did the program terminate" ? In such case on you might get a core dump of crashed application (in case of normal termination I assume you have return codes), and you can inspect it later to either get crash reason or possibly also try to recover some data. For instructions how to collect dumps on Windows, you may check out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However, this is also a feature that is more useful in development environment than in production.

Comment: Also in production environment and it can't make my application much slower.

Comment: For the exact problem you described, I think that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571794/c-write-to-read-from-invalid-out-of-bound-array-index contains the answer - if memory is allocated to your process, there is nothing you can do in general, and not really anything you can do without overheard. However, if this application uses STL, you may link against debug version of this library - it will make code significantly slower, but should help. In case you consider Clang/GCC build, you may also try AddressSanitizer, it helps with such issues sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If You can't modify above program's source then run it in 'outside' environment (shell) and get returned value and test it against 0 - any other value would me incorrect behavior.

It is also good to verify such programs' input data that you know it can't handle so rather than waiting for it to crash you can prevent it from happening.

If You could modify program then simple solution would be to use std::vector or std::deque which are similar but important is to use **at()** method and not the **operator[]** operator as the **at()** method checks bounds

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<int> T(100);

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        T[i] = i;
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<T.at(x)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

if **at()** will be called with bad out-of-bound parameter then exception will be throw which You can catch like this:

```
try{
    cin>>x;
    cout<<T.at(x)<<endl;
}
catch(...)
{
    cout << "exception while accessing vector's data" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't modify program's source. And like I wrote above, program prints random number and returns 0 in this case.